# Why threadExecutionWidth is not a property of MTLDevice?

Tags: ios, gpgpu, metal

As I understand `threadExecutionWidth` in Metal (aka warp, aka wavefront in other frameworks) is inherently a property of a GPU architecture.

There're many properties that depend solely on the GPU architecture like `maxThreadsPerThreadgroup` or `maxBufferLength` and Metal (as expected) makes them to be properties of `MTLDevice` object. Why then `threadExecutionWidth` is a property of `MTLComputePipelineState`? Does it mean that we can somehow make two `MTLComputePipelineState` with different `threadExecutionWidth`'s or my understanding of `threadExecutionWidth` being a characteristic of the GPU itself is wrong?

Comment: Intel GPUs can have different `threadExecutionWidth` based on what the compiler decides is best for residency. AMD and Apple GPUs I think have fixed thread execution width. But as an API, yes, `threadExecutionWidth` is a property of a pipeline state and not the device.

Answer (score 1):

Per [Apple / Debug GPU-side errors in Metal](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10616/) Shader Validation feature can change `threadExecutionWidth`.

> Enabling the feature may also change some queries to return different
> values. In particular, you should always check the
> `maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup` and the `threadExecutionWidth`
> properties of a compute pipeline state as these two may change when
> Shader Validation is enabled.

So it seems that in rare cases `threadExecutionWidth` can depend on different software configuration and not only hardware. Although I wasn't able to catch this on my Apple Silicon.

Also, as @JustSomeGuy mentioned in the comment, unlike Apple GPUs Intel GPUs can have different `threadExecutionWidth` for different pipeline states just by design, as I understand it.